# State equations for a linear mechanical system

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

**The problem:**
The equations of motion of a lumped mechanical system undergoing small motions can be expressed as
$$
Mq'' + Dq' + Kq = f ~~~~ (1)
$$
(using primes instead of dots on top of the $q$s) where $q(t) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is the vector of deflections, $M$, $D$, and $K$ are the mass, damping, and stiffness matrices, respectively, and $f(t) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is the vector of externally applied forces. Assuming $M$ is invertible, write linear system equations for the mechanical system, with the state $x = [q^T~~q'^T]^T$, input $u = f$, and output $y = q$.

(The above is a homework problem corresponding to a class I'm voluntarily taking on my own.)

**What I've done so far:**
From (1), we can apply $M^{-1}$ to both sides to obtain
$$
q'' = M^{-1}f - (M^{-1}Dq' + M^{-1}Kq).
$$

What I'm struggling with is that the output is supposed to be $q$, when what I have can be written as a linear equation $y(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$ with
$$
A = -\begin{bmatrix} M^{-1}K \\ M^{-1}D \end{bmatrix}, ~~~ x = [q^T~~q'^T]^T, ~~~ B = M^{-1}, ~~~ u = f 
$$
but where $y = q''$, not $y = q$.

**Question:** Am I missing something here? Did the problem mean to say that the output $y$ should be $q''$? If I am missing something (and I probably am), any ***hints*** as to what that is would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling $q_1 = q, q_2 = \dot q_1$ we have

$$
\cases{
\dot q_1 = q_2\\
\dot q_2 = -M^{-1}K q_1-M^{-1}D q_2+M^{-1}f
}
$$

and then

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\dot q_1\\
\dot q_2 
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & I\\
-M^{-1}K &-M^{-1}D 
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}
q_1\\
q_2 
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
M^{-1}
\end{array}\right)u
$$

and

$$
y = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
I & 0 
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
q_1\\
q_2 
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Actually, shouldn't that second line be $q_2' = M^{-1}f - M^{-1}Kq_1 + \dots$?  I could be wrong, but I think you may have an accidental extra negative sign.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Now it is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are the one defining the output $y$, not the equations, so if you want (or need) the output to be $q$ just set
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},$$
and
$$B = 0,$$
then 
$$ y = \begin{bmatrix}q &q'\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = q.$$